# SwiftUI ViewModifier for custom View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state, viewmodifier

Is there a way to create a modifier to update a `@State private var` in the view being modified?

I have a custom view that returns either a `Text` with a "dynamic" background color OR a `Circle` with a "dynamic" foreground color.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var theText = ""
    
    @State private var color = Color(.purple)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if theText.isEmpty {          // If there's no theText, a Circle is created
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            } else {                      // If theText is provided, a Text is created
                Text(theText)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(color))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I re-use this view in different parts around my app. As you can see, the only parameter I need to specify is `theText`. So, the possible ways to create this ChildView are as follows:

```
struct SomeParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ChildView()   // <- Will create a circle

            ChildView(theText: "Hello world!")   // <- Will create a text with background
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Nothing fancy so far. Now, what I need is to create (maybe) a modifier or the like so that in the parent views I can change the value of that `@State private var color` from `.red` to other color if I need more customization on that ChildView. Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
struct SomeOtherParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ChildView()

            ChildView(theText: "Hello world!")
                .someModifierOrTheLike(color: Color.green)   // <- what I think I need
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could just remove the `private` keyword from that `var` and pass the `color` as parameter in the constructor (ex: `ChildView(theText: "Hello World", color: .green)`), but I don't think that's the way to solve this problem, because if I need more customization on the child view I'd end up with a very large constructor.

So, Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm looking for? Hope I explained myself :)
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is your view and modifiers are just functions that generate another, modified, view, so... here is some possible simple way to achieve what you want.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var theText = ""
    
    @State private var color = Color(.purple)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if theText.isEmpty {          // If there's no theText, a Circle is created
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            } else {                      // If theText is provided, a Text is created
                Text(theText)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(color))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // simply modify self, as self is just a value
    public func someModifierOrTheLike(color: Color) -> some View {
        var view = self
        view._color = State(initialValue: color)
        return view.id(UUID())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, it's perfect! I didn't have any idea about State(initialValue:). This is what I was looking for, thanks!!! :D

Comment: Hi @Asperi, The modifier doesn't work in the following scenario: In the parent view, add the modifier to the child view and consider using a dynamic color based on a State Boolean variable (ex: "@State var toggleColor = false"), so the call to the modifier looks like this: ". someModifierOrTheLike(color: toggleColor ? .red : .blue)". In this scenario, "someModifierOrTheLike" isn't updating the color on the child view. Any ideas?

Comment: This of course out of scope of initial question... but see updated variant that covers new case.

Comment: @Asperi Hi!
Do you have a solution how to chain modifiers like this?
The problem is that view.id() casts the custom view to general some View.

Comment: Wow, incredible.  So much of SwiftUI's workings are so mysterious that it's elusive, but of course modifying a view would merely involve taking the view and modifying it.  That also really showcases an advantage to the use of value types for view descriptors.

Answer (score 4):

Using a custom ViewModifier is indeed a way to help expose a simpler interface to users, but the general idea of how to pass customization parameters to a View (other than using an `init`), is via environment variables with `.environment`.

```
struct MyColorKey: EnvironmentKey {
   static var defaultValue: Color = .black
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
   var myColor: Color {
      get { self[MyColorKey] }
      set { self[MyColorKey] = newValue }
   }
}
```

Then you could rely on this in your View:

```
struct ChildView: View {
   @Environment(\.myColor) var color: Color

   var body: some View {
      Circle()
         .foregroundColor(color)
         .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
   }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
ChildView()
   .environment(\.myColor, .blue)
```

---

You can make it somewhat nicer by using a view modifier:

```
struct MyColorModifier: ViewModifier {
   var color: Color

   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      content
         .environment(\.myColor, color)
   }
}

extension ChildView {
   func myColor(_ color: Color) { 
      self.modifier(MyColorModifier(color: color) 
   }
}
```

```
ChildView()
   .myColor(.blue)
```

---

Of course, if you have multiple customizations settings or if this is too low-level for the user, you could create a ViewModifier that exposes a subset of them, or create a type that encapsulates a style, like SwiftUI does with a [`.buttonStyle(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/buttonstyle(_:)-66fbx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can chain methods based on Asperi`s answer:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @State private var foregroundColor = Color.red
    @State private var backgroundColor = Color.blue

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
            .background(backgroundColor)
    }

    func foreground(color: Color) -> ChildView {
        var view = self
        view._foregroundColor = State(initialValue: color)
        return view
    }

    func background(color: Color) -> ChildView {
        var view = self
        view._backgroundColor = State(initialValue: color)
        return view
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
            .foreground(color: .yellow)
            .background(color: .green)
            .id(UUID())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using `@State` property wrapper, which you actually **don't need**.

We use any property wrapper e.g. `@State` if there's a way to change the value of the state from your view. But notice that you don't ever change the value `color` from inside your view.

Yes, you modify your view from some custom modifier function's made using builder pattern. But in that case you don't need the state variable, also because you eventually create another view and return (as per Asperi's answer).

So I'd suggest the following code in your use-case scenario:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    var theText = ""
    
    init(theText: String) {
        self.theText = theText
    }
    
    private var color = Color(.purple)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if theText.isEmpty {          // If there's no theText, a Circle is created
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            } else {                      // If theText is provided, a Text is created
                Text(theText)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                    .foregroundColor(color))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // simply modify self, as self is just a value
    public func customModifier(color: Color) -> ChildView {
        var view = self
        view.color = color
        return view
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(theText: "abd")
            .customModifier(color: .green)
    }
}
```

I hope it improves your code.

As per as Apple's suggestion **we should use @State variable only when the property is mutable from inside the view itself** (Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state).